# File.exists() works but Files.readAllBytes() fails with NoSuchFileException

Tags: java, file, relative-path, nosuchfileexception

I am trying to read a text file in Java and I get `NoSuchFileException`.

I tried to check if the file path exists and it returns true. Here is my code.

```
            final File actualFile = new File(filePath);
            if (actualFile.exists()) {
                log.info("ACTUALFILE exists");
            } else {
                log.info("ACTUALFILE does not exist");
            }

            String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

I get the following exception.

```
ACTUALFILE exists

java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: my-file.json
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
at java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Files.java:3152) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
```

Why is Files.readAllBytes() not able to find the file? Am I missing something here?

[Update 1]
Here is the file permissions `-rwxr-xr-x`.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a directory? `File.exists` will return `true` on directories, but you can't read bytes from them.

Comment: Do you have read access to the file?

Comment: Are you running it via any editor or command line? And the file is in the root folder of the project, right?

Comment: Yes, the file is in the root folder of the project. It is an actual json.file. I have `-rwxr-xr-x` for the File permissions.

Comment: I think the problem may be `Paths.get(filePath)`. Try `actualFile.toPath()` instead

Comment: try using this: `String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(new File(filePath).toPath()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Comment: Use the `Path`, `Paths`, and `Files` classes only.  Don’t use java.io.File at all, as it is old and obsolete.  Test for the file’s existence using [Files.exists](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#exists(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.LinkOption...)) or [Files.isReadable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#isReadable(java.nio.file.Path)) (in the java.nio.file package), not File.exists (in the java.io package).